# Where does one go to get a language identified?

Tags: transcription, translation, language-identification

I have a massive book from the pawn shop (i make conlangs and loved the script), and it seems to have an alphabetic 36-character script that doesn't match up to anything on omniglot or the like. I'd like to read my book, so I need to talk to a language ID specialist or find some sort of language stack exchange that can be of assistance. Moreover, once I ID the language I'd also like to translate it.

Transcription or images of, illustrations from, and information about the text is all available upon request in the form of links to files.

Any information would be welcomed. Thank you for your time.

Comment: There are Facebook linguistic groups, like _Polyglots (The Community)_ (60K members) or _Omniglot fan club_ (30K members), you can try and ask them to help you.

Comment: There's no copyright info or anything on it?

Comment: It's handwritten @Malady.

Comment: I don't use Facebook, but I'll try anything just to read my book. @YellowSky.

Comment: StackExchange has basically its own image hosting, so you don't need to use an external: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: @Malady I tried **linguistics stack exchange**, but you aren't allowed to ask Language ID/Translation questions. If you do, they get closed. Is there _any_ stack exchange where such a question would be allowed? I tried asking meta, but that yielded exactly zero answers.

Comment: I see your image, https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSrZR.jpg ... Would be better if flatter, but maybe try the list-of-languages tag asking questions like https://www.quora.com/What-language-has-a-backwards-K, although I can't see any questions about the symbols of a language in that tag, and your language doesn't seem to be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisu_language#Pollard_alphabet ? ...... Maaaybe try https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols, and ask about the symbols / letters of your language.

Comment: I posted this in chat, but the facebook group "guess the language", whilst primarily intended as a game where askers post an excerpt of a language for others to guess is full of people who are good at identifying languages and has sometimes got good traction for texts where the asker does not known the answer. I'd recommend including as many pictures as you have (taken as clearly as possible, so flat and well-lit) and including all the info you have on it (e.g. roughly where you purchased it)